# moving a wordpress site to a new provider

Tags: wordpress, dns, web

I have  friend who wants to move his site to a new provider.

The site in question is a wordpress restaurant site which uses a wp shoppingcart plug-in.

Now the question is, is there anything i need to take extra care of when i move the files and domain to the new provider or is it really that simple?
There is no special connection between the old providers ip and the shoppingcart that will break the page when moved?

Im very new to this, so appriciate all the advice i can get.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you may have to look out for within wordpress when doing the transfer.

First is checking the IP hasn't been set anywhere and that it is the domain url being used on the GUID's or links within posts. Using a plugin such as `find and replace` (http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) will help find all the errors.

The next problem i have encountered the most is the database connections. Be sure to edit the wp-config.php with the new database details and also amend any other document which they may be included in. I have transfered some websites before and the new provider might have added their own prefix or the `MySQL` server may not be localhost.

If the website isn't a simple move and requires a new install of WordPress, remember to transfer the theme and all of the plugins including the settings first. THEN install the backup of data. If you import the backed up data before having everything ready, it can cause pages to break or have missing elements.

Within the shopping cart, you will need to check that there are no payment gateways pointing towards a specific IP. SagePay for example uses an IP to know that `POST` requests are coming from the right place.

Other than that transfers usually go smoothly, though dont expect the DNS record to be amended instantly, the DNS can sometimes take a couple of hours to update so just be patient.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that domain is same and you are just changing the hosting provider. Let us say your current web hosting is 'X' and new web hosting is 'Y'. So, I assume you are trying to move yoursite.com from Hosting X to Y.

First thing, I would do is change the TTL value of X record to the lowest possible value (say 1 Min).

Move all the files and database to Hosting Y. Make appropriate changes in database configuration in wp-config.php moved on Hosting Y. Open Hosts file on your computer and add the following entry in that hosts file (Don't forget to replace IP_ADDRESS_OF_HOSTING_Y with real IP address of Hosting Y and also replace yoursite.com with your site)

IP_ADDRESS_OF_HOSTING_Y yoursite.com

After adding above entry in hosts file, restart your browser and open your website. Now, it will show the new website. Check if it is working properly. Fix the issues that you might find on new server. If everything is working perfectly, then remove the entry added in the Hosts file and restart the browser.

Assuming that you have confirmed everything is working fine on new server, now make changes in the wp-config.php file present on server X and point the database to Hosting Y's database. So that if any user comes to your site and makes the comment, the comment will go to Hosting Y's database.

After this, Change the X record to newer IP address. After TWICE of old TTL value(in this case 48 Hours), you can turn off the services by HOSTING X. Therefore, before changing the TTL value to 1 min if it was 24 Hours, then after 48 hours, you can turn off the service provided by HOSTING X.

After 48 Hours, you can again increase the value of TTL to the original TTL value(in this case 24 hours).